# How to suppress the author bookmark generated by svmult with bookmark package without suppressing the TOC entry?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

The `bookmark` package is useful for automatically generating bookmarks within Springer's `svmult` document class, intended for books with individual author contributions appearing as chapters.  The TOC generated is acceptable, but a bookmark is added that refers to the authors of the chapter, and all sections of the chapter are nested under the bookmark with the authors' names.  This looks a bit ugly.

How can I suppress the bookmarks generated from the authors lists without damaging the TOC or, say, manually modifying the resultant PDF in Acrobat?

Alternatively, how can I alter the nesting level of author?  The usual `hypersetup` trick doesn't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\title{MWE Chapter}
\author{Me, Myself, and I}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Heiko's answer is perfect.  Thanks for the explanation to go with it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class `svnmulti` does not define bookmark level entries for `titlech` and `authorch` that are used in the table of contents for the title and the author. Package `hyperref` then uses the default `0`:

```
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown titlech defaults to 0.
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown authorch defaults to 0.
```

Both the warnings can be avoided and the author can be put a level deeper by providing the missing bookmark levels, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@titlech}{0} 
\edef\toclevel@authorch{\the\numexpr\toclevel@titlech+1} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\title{MWE Chapter}
\author{Me, Myself, and I}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The same way, the entry for the author can be suppressed by using a value that is larger than the `bookmarksdepth`, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@titlech}{0}
\def\toclevel@authorch{1000}
\makeatother
```

Similar to `tocdepth`, the entries are not added to the bookmarks, if their level is larger.

**Update**

With version 2004/05/18 v3.14, found in a [link](https://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/125808/application/zip/svmult.zip) in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153197/how-to-install-svmult#comment349830_153197)
for question "[How to Install SVMult](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153197/16967)", an updated example:

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@title{-1}
\def\toclevel@author{0}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\title{MWE Chapter}
\author{Me, Myself, and I}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the last paragraph, I think `\def\toclevel@authorch}{1000}` has to be replaced with `\def\toclevel@authorch{1000}` right?

Comment: I have used the suggested solution. It does not produce an error, but the "Package hyperref Warning" messages still stay and the bookmark keeps the mentioned ugly form.

Comment: With svmult 2018/01/11 v5.5, the original solution works.