# How to Install SVMult

Tags: packages, document-classes, sv-classes

I'm struggling actually with an article to send to Springer. They ask me to use `SVMult` class. In my case I use `\documentclass{SVMult}` unsuccesfully. It is impossible to send or even continue writing my document. It's bugging. MikTeX says this:

> "! LaTeX Error: File `SVMult.cls' not found.
>   Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: cls) Enter file name"

I've tried to see if there is a package named `SVMUlt` but there is none.

How to install and use `SVMult`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You have to download `svmult.cls` from Springer.

Comment: ...[here's a link](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/125808/application/zip/svmult.zip) and you might want to match the case of the name of the actual `cls` file (`svmult.cls`).

Comment: I attempt to run the svmult.cls contained into this link. But results are the following:   ("C:/Users/Achille/Desktop/MAF conference/mult/styles/svmult.cls"
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \NeedsTeXFormat
                    {LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
?   No way impossible to go further.

Answer (score 1):

`SVMult` is made by the german Springer Verlag. See their official FTP repository at ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/: There are two directories `svmult` and the newer one [`svmult1`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svmultt1/). I think the latest `svmult.cls` from 2007 can be found at `svmultt1/styles/svmult.cls`.