# How to run Springer's SVMult class (showing error)

Tags: document-classes, sv-classes

I am using Winedt editor. 
I am trying to create a document with Springer's SVMult class. 
When I am running, it is showing SVMult.cls' not found. I have never used this document class before and it is quite confusing as there are so many .tex files. I am attaching a screenshot of the folder ***Editor*** provided by the Springer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[graybox, envcountchap]{svmult}
```

% in the Reference Guide

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}        % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{helvet}          % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
\usepackage{courier}         % selects Courier as typewriter font
%\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                         % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\include{dedic}
\include{foreword}
\include{preface}
\include{acknow}

\tableofcontents
\include{cblist}
\include{acronym}


\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{part}
\include{author}


\backmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
\include{appendix}
\include{glossary}
\printindex


\end{document}
```

I tried to edit .tex file named "editor" and got it run. But it showing an error. Kindly help. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Did you see the posting [How to Install SVMult](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153197/5001)?

Comment: Do I need to save svmult Latex class and svind.ist in the same folder where editor.tex file is saved?

Comment: The files can be in any directory that's searched by TeX. As a starter, I'd keep the cls and ist files in the directory where you main tex file (the one that features the `\documentclass` statement) is located.

Comment: @Mico I did the same and compiled but still getting error

Comment: "I ... still getting error". *Which* error? Sorry, my mind-reading skills are worthless.