# Suppress one particular Part from Table of Contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, bookmarks

I have the PDF set up so that the TOC and PDF bookmarks are generated.

However, I want to get rid of the Part "Front Matter" from the TOC (but not the sections under this part), while still generating the Part "Front Matter" in my PDF bookmarks. How can I do this?

Perhaps best explained by the screenshot of the PDF:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{refcount}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\begin{document}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Front Matter}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Cover}
Cover Art inserted here.

\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents} \tableofcontents
\textbf{\LARGE{}About This Book}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{About This Book}

\part{The First Part}
\section{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you mean `\frontmatter`?

Comment: @AML: What do you mean? All I want to know is how to suppress particular Parts (or sections or subsections) from the TOC, without also suppressing them from the PDF bookmarks.

Comment: I think this question could be relevant to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123575/how-to-suppress-the-author-bookmark-generated-by-svmult-with-bookmark-package-wi. Also, you should try to get @HeikoOberdiek to help with this if possible, since he is the `hyperref` master.

Comment: You can use `\bookmark[level=part,dest=frontmatter]{Front Matter}` and remove `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline` for front matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\bookmark[level=part,dest=frontmatter]{Front Matter}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{refcount}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\begin{document}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=frontmatter]{Front Matter}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Cover}
Cover Art inserted here.

\clearpage
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\section{About This Book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\part{The First Part}
\section{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]